# adding some records to the database in django using json file

Tags: database, django, json

My django application has some 500 records in various tables in the database(`postgres`).I want to add some 4 more records to a particular table.I have created(edited by hand )a json file that represents the new data to be added and I have taken care to provide them new `id`s so that they don't conflict with existing records in db.

What I want to know is whether the existing data(the original 500 records) will be deleted when I call

```
django-admin.py loaddata mydata.json
```

Or will the new data be added to the existing records?

p.s:
Is there any way I can convert the whole data in db into a json file?Using serializers is time consuming when there are many model classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do a backup before the loaddata if it's mission critical.

That said, loaddata just adds **or updates** records, it doesn't delete the existing ones.

Comment: thank you..but how do you take a backup of data from postgres in ubuntu?

Comment: That's actually another question. The command to use is pg_dump. For example you can dump with: pg_dump -x -F c -f /path/to/dump database_name. Then restore with: pg_restore --disable-triggers -d database_name /path/to/dump. Read the docs on these commands flags please.

Comment: `django-admin` also has a tool for dumping the data from your database in a format that can later be read by `loaddata`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#dumpdata-appname-appname-appname-model